# Mysql special characters

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, collation

I need to store on my Mysql database values like: Badaẖšan.
On this particular case the DB is saving Badah?šan.
I'm using Charset: UTF8 and Collation: utf8_unicode_ci.

What Charset/Collation should I use to store the correct value?

**EDIT:**

I'm using Codeigniter.
Config:
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';

Code.

```
$this->db->query("INSERT INTO region (country_name) VALUES ('Badaẖšan')");
```

which returns:

```
Badah?šan
```

Using the MySQL GUI Tool SQLyog and running the query:

```
INSERT INTO `region` (country_name) VALUES ('Badaẖšan')
```

returns the warning:
    Warning Code : 1366
    Incorrect string value: '\xCC\xB1\xC5\xA1an' for column 'country_name' at row 1

and once again the value inserted is:

```
Badah?šan
```

**EDIT2:**

Problem solved.
Although the table had the correct Charset, the columns were set to latin1.
That's why the result was broken.
I'm very sorry for the inconvenience.
This thread can be closed.

Comment: What's the *connection charset* between your app and MySQL?

Comment: Can't reproduce... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ca843/1/0, needs more information.

Comment: Added new info to my initial question. Thks!